# Getting grails application version from within the app

Tags: grails

I'd like to display the application version in the footer of my app.  Is there a way to get the value of the app.version variable in the application.properties file at runtime?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `<g:meta>`: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/meta.html

Answer (score 23):

ApplicationHolder is depreciated.

You can use

```
Holders.grailsApplication.metadata['app.version']
```

or inject grailsApplication bean by adding field:

```
def grailsApplication
```

and access to application version

```
grailsApplication.metadata['app.version']
```

Comment: In Grails 3.0 it looks like the way to go is: `grailsApplication.metadata.getApplicationVersion()` or `grailsApplication.config.info.app.version`

Answer (score 5):

You can also use: ApplicationHolder.application.metadata['app.version']

Comment: While this is true, in my particular case I want to include the text in the output.  Burt's answer is quicker/easier to do in a GSP page.